# Is it possible to dequeue from ANYDATA Synchronous Capture queue using JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, advanced-queuing

What I'm trying to do is subscribe to all changes in Oracle table using [Synchronous Capture](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28322/man_gen_rep.htm#CEGBFIFJ), from Java process.

ANYDATA queue is created with

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.SET_UP_QUEUE(
    queue_table  => 'hcb_qtab_any',
    queue_name   => 'hcb_queue_any',
    queue_user   => 'gguser');
END;
```

And then I'm using code from [Dequeue using Java for Oracle 11g queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608658/dequeue-using-java-for-oracle-11g-queue) as an example. I'm trying to do

```
message = queue.dequeue(deq_option, XMLType.getORADataFactory());
```

But all I get is `oracle.AQ.AQOracleSQLException`: Error creating descriptor: `Invalid arguments`. I've debugged it a bit, it turns out, for ANYDATA `TypeDescriptor.getTypeDescriptor()` will return OpaqueDescriptor which isn't considered as `StructDescriptor.isValidObject()`.

I did another take using thin JDBC AQ:

```
AQDequeueOptions deqopt = new AQDequeueOptions();
deqopt.setConsumerName("subscriber1");
AQMessage msg = conn.dequeue("hcb_queue_any", deqopt, "SYS.ANYDATA");
OPAQUE opq = (OPAQUE)msg.getANYDATAPayload().accessDatum();
```

And I'm facing a new unique problem here. This OPAQUE has `getDescriptor().getTypeName() == "XMLTYPE"`, so I would very much like to turn it to XML. But there's a problem: Only thin JDBC driver supports AQ, while only ACI driver supports turning OPAQUE to XML. I'm getting `Only LOB or String Storage is supported in Thin XMLType` error when I'm trying to do `new XMLType(opq)`

How do I get [Synchronous Capture XML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14229/ap_xmlschema.htm) from AQ using JDBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a stored procedure and dequeue the message in PL/SQL and convert it to XML text and return it as a CLOB. Then you can call the stored procedure from Java with JDBC. I have used a similar workaround before when the plain AQ API lacked a feature.

Example:

```
create or replace procedure dequeue_lcr(
    p_queue_name   varchar2,
    p_consumer     varchar2,
    p_wait_seconds number,
    p_lcr          out clob) as
  deq_lcr     anydata;
  deq_xml     xmltype;
  msgid       raw(16); 
  deqopt      dbms_aq.dequeue_options_t; 
  mprop       dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
  no_messages exception; 
  pragma exception_init (no_messages, -25228);
begin
  deqopt.consumer_name := p_consumer;
  deqopt.wait := p_wait_seconds;
  deqopt.navigation := dbms_aq.first_message;
  deqopt.dequeue_mode  := dbms_aq.remove;
  begin
    dbms_aq.dequeue( 
      queue_name         =>  p_queue_name,
      dequeue_options    =>  deqopt,
      message_properties =>  mprop,
      payload            =>  deq_lcr,
      msgid              =>  msgid);
     deq_xml := dbms_streams.convert_lcr_to_xml(deq_lcr);
     p_lcr := deq_xml.getclobval();    
     commit;
  exception
    when no_messages then
      p_lcr := null;
  end;
end;
```

This works when I call it from PL/SQL with the proper queue and consumer:

```
declare
  v_clob clob;
begin
  dequeue_lcr('aqtest.hcb_queue_any', 'LOCAL_AGENT', 5, v_clob);
  if (v_clob is not null) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Data: ' || v_clob);
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('No messages');  
  end if;
end;
```

Just make the call from Java with a CallableStatement with a clob as output parameter and you should be good to go!

Comment: I think that's a viable solution, can you add an example of such stored procedure?

Comment: I'll try to find some time in the weekend.