# Oracle Advance Queue

Tags: oracle, advanced-queuing

I need to create xml payload and send that to oracle advance queue. I knew to create xmlpayload using pl/sql. but no idea about oracle AQ's. 
Could somebody please help me how to achieve this. how to create AQ's and send payload to AQ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AQ is covered quite well with examples in the official documentation, see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADQUE/aq_opers.htm#ADQUE1000. For XML I would post the message as text or JMS text. Try the official samples and ask more specific questions if you run into problems!

Comment: Thanks ewramner.. i will try the same

Comment: I am able to create queues. how to send data from one table to this queue whenever there is a new record insertion happens. 
how do I pass values and enqueue ?

Comment: That is a different question. For automatically capturing inserts see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634691/is-it-possible-to-dequeue-from-anydata-synchronous-capture-queue-using-jdbc. Alternatively you can create a trigger on the table and do the enqueue from there.